# How many ways to implement UI for support mutilple devices (screen)

Tags: android

I want to create an application with a responsive UI for all kind of screens in Android. I just know one way is we create many folders that contain the content for different kinds of layout, images etc., like this:

[image]

So could anyone give me any other ways (solution)?

Comment: one way is to use dimen file. But i also wanted to know a fully described answer for this question. like what should we do for text size and what about assets icons images etc

Comment: you are using layout-small layout-large .... so on .. what about layout-hdpi layout-mdpi layout-xhdpi ... and so on what is the difference ??

Comment: the image is just the example, i'm also finding a way to implements it :D

Comment: @AdeelTurk the difference is that small-normal-large-xlarge are screen SIZES while mdpi-hdpi-xdpi and so on are screen densities. You can have mobile phones with mdpi and xxxhdpi screens but both will have normal-sized screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Creating layouts for different screen sizes is a common practice but let think if you want to update your layout then you have to do a lot of things.

We have a lot of ways to support different screens.

- Provide different layouts for different screen sizes
- Provide more resource, create different bitmaps (image etc) for each type of screens.
- Use dp,sp instead of pixel
- Explicitly declare in the manifest which screen sizes your application supports
- Use 9 patch image to auto scale

Comment: Great! Thank you. (y)

Answer (score 2):

Use RelativeLayout in XML and between that design your layout.
It support Small Screen , Medium Screen, and Tablet also.

Comment: all of it is define in android developer official site, right? but I want the high level way to do that, not detail like this.

Answer (score 2):

try this code in your mainfest:

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
              android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
              android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
              android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
              android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

try this ref: [check this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html)

Comment: with this way, we no need to create different folder content layout for each screen size, right?

Comment: let me try it and response for you :)

Comment: Ok sure but please refer reference link

Comment: Note: Screen compatibility mode is not a mode in which you should want your application to run—it causes pixelation and blurring in your UI, due to zooming. The proper way to make your application work well on large screens is to follow the guide to Supporting Multiple Screens and provide alternative layouts for different screen sizes.

Comment: maye it just a provisional solution

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need another solution? Creating layouts for different screen sizes is a common practice and nothing works better now. This way you can implement really responsive design in your app.

Comment: yes, i know.. but I want other way that more quickly or automaticaly than this. :D I think we can do that automaticaly

Comment: Well, in this case, I think, responsive design is not actually what you want. The "responsive design" means that your app looks and feels nice and user-friendly on any device with any screen size or orientation. This usually results in different layouts for different configurations. What you want is a quick solution and this is not good for user experience.